# Add widget after every nth post on home page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how I could add different custom widgets to my front page (like instagram, pinterest, newsletter, videos) after a certain number of posts appear.  An example of this is http://margoandme.com , however unlike this blog I would like the widgets to keep appearing after every nth posts even after you go to the next page.

How would I accomplish this?  Would I code the widgets (like one for instagram) in their own php file, and than add the php file to the my front page loop?  If I do this than how would I get each of them to appear after every nth post.  I'm thinking I want about 5 widgets and I want one of them to appear after every 5 posts.

my front-page.php

```html
<?php

get_header();
get_template_part ('post-template/trendingg'); 
?>



<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
                paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
                posts_per_page: 15  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
            },
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 15, // i use 1 for testing
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;
        }?>
    <?php
}?>
</section>

<button id="load_more_btn">Load More Posts</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

my functions.php

```html
//FRONT PAGE
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');

function my_load_more_function() {

    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"])
    ] );


    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
 <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
                                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;

        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

***my updated front-page.php based on suggestions

```html
<?php

get_header();
get_template_part ('post-template/trendingg'); 
?>



<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
                paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
                posts_per_page: 15  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
            },
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
                jQuery("#content-load-more-btn").html("<h4 class='no-more-load'>No more items to load.</h4>");
                jQuery('.no-more-load').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
     $(document).ready(function () {          
 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.no-more-show').slideUp("slow");
            }, 5000);
});
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 15, // i use 1 for testing
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $widgetCount = 0;
$widgets = ['widgets/shop-widget.php','widgets/insta-widget.php','widgets/video-widget.php','widgets/pinterest-widget.php'];
$numWidgets = count($widgets);
            $the_query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... 
                 if ($widgetCount < $numWidgets) { //if we haven't used all the widgets
            include($widgets[$widgetCount]); //include next widget
            $widgetCount++; //increment the count
        }

                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;
        }?>
    <?php
}?>
</section>
 <div id="content-load-more-btn">
<button id="load_more_btn">Load More Posts</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

***my updated functions.php based on suggestions

```html
//FRONT PAGE
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');

function my_load_more_function() {

    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"])
    ] );


    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $widgetCount = 0;
$widgets = ['widgets/shop-widget.php','widgets/insta-widget.php','widgets/video-widget.php','widgets/pinterest-widget.php'];
$numWidgets = count($widgets);
                $query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... 
                        if ($widgetCount < $numWidgets) { //if we haven't used all the widgets
            include($widgets[$widgetCount]); //include next widget
            $widgetCount++; //increment the count
        }
                ?>
 <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
                                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;

        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have a conditional statement comparing the index of your loop to being divisible by 5  using the PHP's [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).  Put your logic inside that `if` statement.

As far as how you would include them, there's any number of ways to do that but you want to ensure they aren't duplicated.

Here's a rough layout assuming you'd just put your widgets in include files:

```
// CREATE A NEW .php FILE FOR EACH OF YOUR WIDGETS AND SAVE
// SAVE THEM TO YOUR SERVER. THEN ADD THE FOLLOWING 3 LINES BEFORE YOUR
// while LOOP. MAKE SURE THE NAMES OF YOUR NEW FILES ARE WHATS IN THE
// 'widgets' ARRAY AND THAT THE PATHS TO THE FILES ARE CORRECT.
$widgetCount = 0;
$widgets = ['twitter.php','insta.php','facebook.php','reddit.php'];
$numWidgets = count($widgets);

// FOLLOWING IS BASED ON YOUR EXISTING WHILE LOOP:
while ($the_query->have_posts()) {  //loop thru posts
    $the_query->the_post();
    if ($i % 5 === 0) { //if post divisible by 5 LOOK FOR THIS IN YOUR CODE!

        // ADD THE FOLLOWING.  THIS WILL ADD ONE OF YOUR WIDGETS FROM
        // FROM THE ARRAY ABOVE.
        if ($widgetCount < $numWidgets) { //if we haven't used all the widgets
            include($widgets[$widgetCount]); //include next widget
            $widgetCount++; //increment the count
        }

        // all your other existing post rendering here.


    } // end of if statement
} // end while loop
```

Comment: I thought I just did?

Comment: This is not a copy/paste solution I've provided here.  Its an explanation as to how you would accomplish what you want to do in a way to educate you on how it works since you're new.  If you're just looking for people to provide you plug and play code, you're in the wrong place.  Examine what I provided compare it to your own code and make an effort to adopt it... and learn.

Comment: I've made some alterations to the example above to hopefully help you better understand whats going on. Sorry for the all caps comments, but I wanted you to know where the changes were.

Comment: Should I add this into my front-page.php or my functions.php, or both?

Comment: What I provided is based on your frontpage.php, compare the two and you'll see where to put it.

Comment: I've updated both my front page and functions based off of your suggestions, however only the shop widget (shop-widget.php) is appearing after every 5 posts.

Comment: I've added the two updated files in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have implemented the Logic, like: **`if( $i % 5 === 0 ) {}`**, you don't need to call the same condition on `functions.php` file. simply add your widget under this **`if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { //Your Widget Code }`** and call it.

Once you have your condition then you'll able to acheive what exactly you need.

For more about Loop and Widgets, please read WordPress support where these things are already defined. (i): https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API and (ii): https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Answer (score 0):

The above methods are not scalable.
If you're looking at social networks for reference, you're looking to do something in a better way.

An example of recommended way would be to have 2 data sets, one will have the posts/feed, and other will have the widgets data.

Example:

```
Posts: [
 [post 1],
 [post 2],
  ...
]
```

Widgets:

```
[
  [
    position: 5,
    widget: 'video',
    src: 'file, path or something',
    template: 'if to pick a specific template',
    ...(width, height)
  ],
  [
    position: 11,
    widget: 'ad',
    src: 'file, path or something',
    template: 'if to pick a specific template',
    ...(width, height)
  ],
]
```

Now when rendering the posts/feed, you just need to combine the 2 before rendering.

This way allows to keep various types of cards/widgets of any template view or data.

I generally combine my cards and call it a feed, and add a 'type' attribute to it. This allows me to also keep a dynamic position for cards, not necessary 5th or 10th for all.

Output:

```
[
  [ type: 'post', title: '', excerpt: '',...]
  [ type: 'video', ...]
  [ type: 'ad', ...]
]
```

And while rendering them in a for loop, you can just check

```
if(type = post)
  echo template('post', $data)
if(type = video) 
  echo template('video', $data)
```

Hope this helps.